# List all objects in Amazon S3 using Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am listing all objects in my bucket.The question is when i am listing all objects,the last object in a batch is again considering in next batch of object and its repeating for next batch.Why is it happening as it should consider only 1000 objects in a batch and should not consider the previous batch object.

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("foo", "bar");
client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
.standard()
.withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
.withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(http://(serviceEndpoint), null(signingRegion is null))
.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
.withChunkedEncodingDisabled(true)
.build();
ObjectListing listing = client.listObjects( "bucketname");
System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(999).getKey());
SomeFunction(listing);

while (listing.isTruncated()) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    listing = client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
    System.out.println("Listing size "+listing.getObjectSummaries().size());
    System.out.println("At 0 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
    System.out.println("At 999 index "+ listing.getObjectSummaries().get(1000).getKey());
    someFunction(listing);
}
```

My ouput is:

```
Listing size 1000
At 0 index folder1/a.gz
At 999 index folder1/b.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------
Listing size 1001
At 0 index folder1/b.gz
At 1000 index folder1/d.gz
---------------------------------------------------------------
Listing size 1001
At 0 index folder1/d.gz
At 1000 index folder1/e.gz
```

As you can see the first batch 999 index is considered in second batch(same) why?It shouldn't happen right?And the next batch is taking 1001 objects including the last one from previous as it should give next 1000 not 1001.Help me solve this.Thank You.

Comment: From where does `At 1000 index` gets printed as you have hardcoded `At 999 index`?

Comment: @user7 From the next batch it is giving 1001 objects,so the last index is 1000 as i printed to show that next batch is taking that 1000 object.

Comment: Does `someFunction` mutate the `listing` by any chance?

Comment: @user7 No it does not mutate the list.Even if i remove that function and run its throwing the same output.

Comment: I tried the same. I couldn't reproduce such a behavior. All object summaries are of size 1000

Comment: Can you try printing `getMarker` and `getNextMarker`? Maybe it can give us some clue.

Comment: @user7 can u show your client connection.Is there any difference in your and mine client connection.

Comment: Check your endpoint, it is pointing to a localhost. So it is not the actual S3 service endpoint. If you're testing this with a mock, check your data. I've tested your code on actual S3 endpoint and I wa able to get list of all objects in the bucket(several thousands).

Comment: I am using the acutal s3 service Endpoint and I am able to get all objects but the problem is one object is repeating after every 1000(last one from previous batch).I didnt come to know why @Rodel -Thank You

Comment: @SachinRT I mean, I didn't get 1001 objects on the while loop. I think you need to check your method someFunction(listing). It might adding something on the listing.

Comment: @Rodel even I remove that function and just printing objects it is giving the same.Is it my client is correct or does it have any difference than you are using client.Can you show your code and result please

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't fit in the note so I put my code here:

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretAccessKey);
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com", region))
        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
        .withChunkedEncodingDisabled(true)
        .build();
ObjectListing listing = s3Client.listObjects(bucket);
int size = listing.getObjectSummaries().size();
if (size > 0) {
    System.out.println("Listing size " + size);
    System.out.println("At 0 index " + listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
    System.out.println("At " + (size - 1) + " index " + listing.getObjectSummaries().get(size - 1).getKey());
}

while(listing.isTruncated()) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    listing = s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing);
    size = listing.getObjectSummaries().size();
    if (size > 0) {
        System.out.println("Listing size " + size);
        System.out.println("At 0 index " + listing.getObjectSummaries().get(0).getKey());
        System.out.println("At " + (size - 1) + " index " + listing.getObjectSummaries().get(size - 1).getKey());
    }
}
```

And here's the result:

```
Listing size 1000
At 0 index file0001.txt
At 999 index file1000.txt
-----------------------------------------------
Listing size 1000
At 0 index file1001.txt
At 999 index file2000.txt
-----------------------------------------------
Listing size 1000
At 0 index file2001.txt
At 999 index file3000.txt
-----------------------------------------------
Listing size 100
At 0 index file3001.txt
At 99 index file3100.txt
```

I changed your code a little on how to output sizes and indexes. By the way I'm using 1.11.330 SDK version.

Comment: Yeah I figured out the problem.It is in my service Endpoint,it is replicating one object i guess.I came to this decision by creating new aws account and bucket and it gave perfect answer.Will there any policy for service Endpoint for that behaviour of replicating object for every 1000 batch.

Comment: withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true) - this give an insight to me to list all contents in an s3 bucket. there is a lot changed but this helped me to resolve my client not listing the bucket contents. ( i am using v2.x )